# Is it possible to install WPA3 on the OnePlus3?

Tags: wi-fi, oneplus-3

As I understand it, WPA3 is software, so it should be possible to install it, right? If so, how?

I would clearly like to have all my devices on the latest security.

Thanks!

Comment: No. WPA3 is not a software. It's a security standard which the hardware manufacturers follow. You need to use a phone which has a Wi-Fi chip with WPA3 support. And your WiFi router should also be supporting WPA3.

Comment: My router supports WPA-3. Is WPA-3 provided in the WiFi client hardware? I thought it was just an algorithm.

Comment: Theoretically it might be possible to make a device WPA3 certified by firmware upgrade. But I don't think that happens on Earth. If your device doesn't already support WPA3, it's very unlikely to get support ever. [Here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-wpa3-owe#implementation) is what you need to do to make your Android device WPA3-compatible. Do you think you can do it on your own; changes to kernel, proprietary Wi-Fi HAL (firmware) and AOSP code (Android 10 at least)? Definitely not.

Answer (score 2):

**Unlikely.**

OnePlus 3 was [released in 2016](https://www.gsmarena.com/oneplus_3-7995.php).

Qualcomm announced [WPA3 mobile chipset support in 2018](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/releases/2018/05/15/qualcomm-integrates-newest-wi-fi-security-standard-across-mobile-and).

> Qualcomm Technologies expects to incorporate WPA3 security features into chipsets in summer 2018 for mobile devices beginning with the Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 845 Mobile Platform

The Android framework started supporting [WPA3 with Android 10](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-wpa3-owe).

and requires:

> Wi-Fi chip with support for WPA3 and OWE

So in addition to using a device with a supporting WiFi chipset, you'll need to be running at least Android 10 as well.

Comment: Sounds like an excuse to get a new phone :D